# Counting Columns of Tables using Hiveql

Tags: sql, powershell, shell, hiveql

I'm trying to count  the Columns for each of my tables using hive.

To find the columns i used the query 'show columns in tablename', then, i used the command:

```
    hive -e 'show columns in tablename' | grep -v 'WARN' (to remove the warning from the count ) | wc -l
```

It give me the correct results.

But when i try to run this for many tables, the command gives me the sum of all columns.

Here's what i've done:

1- Created a hql file containing all the queries like this:

```
show columns in tablename1;
show columns in tablename2;
```

Then, i used the same command, but instead of hive -e, i used hive -f :

```
hive -f file.hql | grep -v 'WARN'  | wc -l
```

The result has only 1 line with what seems the sum of all columns.

I wanted something like:

`tablename1 columsnumber1`

`tablename2 columnsnumber2`

Comment: Write a loop in your shell script?  One iteration per table, allowing you to run your initial command once per table?

Comment: Why did you tag powershell?

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
cat queries.txt | while read line; do eval "hive -e $line" | grep -v WARN | wc -l ; done > outpux.txt
```